# Why does not Entity Framework Core have an Upsert (AddOrUpdate) and Synchronize(AddOrUpdateOrDelete) command?

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I faced a situation where I need to maintain some database tables in sync with a Rest API. There is a daemon that keeps hitting this endpoint and has to sync the related tables.

I'm using ef core and I found only the standard Add and AddRange methods but nothing like **Upsert** or **Synchronize**. I searched a little bit and found that some proprietary nugget packages provide this but I need something open-source.

Is there a reason why this is not supported directly in EF Core ?

Comment: I suspect you're misusing EF Core as if it were just a low level data access library. It's not, it's an ORM. ORMs are meant to map Objects to Relational tables *only*. All ORMs cache changes and *only* persist them when you call the appropriate method, in this case `SaveChangesAsync`. When that happens, the ORM generates the necessary SQL queries to INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE *all* changes. This way ORMs implement Unit-of-Work out of the box. In fact. EF Core *does* use "upset" through the MERGE command to batch multiple operations

Comment: So the real question is, why are you looking for explicit Insert, Update or Delete commands in the *ORM*? Even `Add` or `AddRange` *don't* execute anything, they just add some objects to a DbContext instance. It's `SaveChangesAsync` that generates the SQL statements

Comment: See this : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/453

Comment: As for third-party packages, unfortunately there are a lot of bad packages and frameworks that try to make a high-level ORM like EF work like ADO.NET. If you want to execute SQL statements directly you don't need EF Core. A better idea would be to use a micro-ORM like eg [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) or ADO.NET directly

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi `Maybe it's a scant comfort to know that AddOrUpdate in EF6 had its own problems, considerably limiting its usefulness.` NHibernate also has issues, because the very idea is problematic. The *only* way an ORM can know that an item exists is to try to load it. That's expensive. A MERGE query is also more expensive than individual INSERT or UPDATE queries and isn't atomic. `MERGE` is implementation-dependent too. MySQL has `REPLACE` for example, with its own problems

Comment: `with a Rest API` in that case, you *know in advance* whether you need to perform an INSERT or UPDATE . A POST is an INSERT by definition, a PUT is an UPDATE. In fact you may have a *different* problem - by default, EF Core will perform an UPDATE if it finds an explicit key value when you really need an INSERT in response to a POST

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I need to keep that database in sync with the Resp API because there are other systems consuming it and it should reflect what's in the  Rest API. Do you have any advises to approach this ?

Comment: That's an ambiguous question - what does `keep in sync` mean? If you want to modify the database in response to REST calls, you already know whether you need to perform an INSERT or UPDATE, so no UPSERT is needed. A PUT isn't allowed to to create a resource

Comment: `it should reflect what's in the Rest API.` it's the other way round, unless that REST API actually stores data somewhere. Is that the case? Are you trying to *request* data from a REST API and store it to a database? That's an ETL scenario, not suitable for ORMs. There are no entities in that case, only tables and rows. The fast and easy way to do this is to store the data to a staging table and move the data to the target table by using a LEFT JOIN based eg on the PK and an UPDATE for matching rows, INSERT for non-matching rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Ok let me rephrase. I don't own the Rest API, I'm a client of it. I have a deamon that runs every 30 minutes pull data from and endpoint and has to update the database tables. By update, I mean it should take the data pulled from the api and try to match it with what's in our database. If what was pulled from the api  is already there then it should be updated, if new stuff was found it should be inserted, and if stuff in the database is not in the pulled data it should be removed. This is what I mean by sync.

Comment: Use a staging table, store all data to it and update the target table using LEFT JOIN. Execute an UPDATE first, then the INSERT to avoid updating the rows you've already inserted. You don't need an ORM for this, there are no entities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yes. I posted the question out of curiosity in the first place. Because I saw that this feature is supported only through proprietary nugget packages. Thank you for the discussion.